Criteria for Human birth
Namasthe to all
In Garud Puran Pretha Khanda, Chapter 46, it's mentioned that one gets a human birth when their punya and paap are equalized

And at same time it's mentioned in Kularnava Tantra that,

Atra janma sahasreshu sahasrairapi PArvati Kadachit labhate jantur
mAnushyam punyasanchayAt
Meaning
[Lord Shiva says to Goddess PArvati] Thousands and thousands of jivas
are getting equally numerous births, but among them only rarely
(kadAchit) one gets a human birth due to its accumulated merits
(punyasanchaya).

And in Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter XLIX, it's mentioned that

Passing through four types of bodies in order of their karmas and
leaving one body after the other a thousand times, taking birth in
human form, and acquiring knowledge due to good acts one obtains
release.
In the eighty four lacs of bodies of creatures one does not acquire
true knowledge anywhere unless one is born as a man.
Here, after thousands of crores of births a creature obtains human
form only sometime due to aggregate of virtue.

My question is,
In preta Khanda it's mentioned after passing through various lower yoni as per their karma, a jiva is born as human once paap and punya gets equal
And in Dharma khanda it's mentioned that Here, after thousands of crores of births a creature obtains human form very rarely due to aggregate of virtue
I have two questions.

Are both same or contradictory to each other?

Are they considered as laws or principles based on which the law of karma works?


Please kindly answer this
Thanks

Well, if you can't see a contradiction in two statements then by definition those statements are not contradictory.
And these statements are more like a consequence of the law of karma rather than the principle on which karma works. Law of karma operates in a very chaotic and nonlinear fashion. You cannot define precise principles of its operation which can be understood by humans.

Okay are you saying both the statements are false ?

@DrUser. Do you mean both the statements are false ? And non functional

@Karthik When did i say that?

Okay sir may be i might have misunderstood.  I thought you told that they are false .  Apologies for the confusion. So just to confirm what they have mentioned that when punya paap is equal a jiva gets human birth is true right as it's it's mentioned in garud puran ?

Request you if you can please answer this question sir https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61502/contradictions-in-srimad-bhagavatham-and-bhagavad-gita

@User44690 Sir i am OCD patient . Pls show mercy and pls reply me i beg you please kindly reply me sir . I have some queries. I need help please can you show mercy and reply me sir.

@Karthik Hi. My apologies. I am a little occupied for a few days so I won't be able to be active online. I will answer once I am a little free.

@DrUser44690 Who is the creator of Laws of Universe ? Is it God ? Or Sages such as Rishi Munis? Who created the laws of nature that govern the functioning of this universe ? Did God create The Laws and in deep meditation sages discovered these Laws which are created by God and wrote scriptures? Or Sages themselves create the laws which governs the universe?

@DrUser44690 Please kindly answer this

@Karthik Hi it seems this is going to be an extended conversation therefore I request that you join my discord server here https://discord.gg/gaFnNcUjFM It would be much more easier to clarify your doubts this way.
